# GeoDjango installation error

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, geodjango

I'm trying to build a GIS application in Django Framework. I completed the GeoDjango installtion (postresql, spatial libraries). I also setup environment variables. I'm using PyCharm as an IDE and have a virtual env set up. But I cannot get the osgeo import to work in my django project. It's not recognized but the import works fine in python shell. Do I need to install all these gis components into my virtualenv site-packages?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would install all the requirements of your Django application, osgeo as well as any djano helper apps, into a virtualenv. Then I would simply tell PyCharm about that virtualenv. [Adding Existing Virtual Environment](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html) tells you how to do that.